# Javadoc link this class

Tags: java, javadoc

Is there a way to something like `{@link this}` in Javadoc?

**this** refers to the current class.

```
public class Manager {
    /**
     * this method does blablabla for {@link this}
     */
    public void method(){
    }
}
```

The generated javadoc for `method()` is `this method does blablabla for Manager`

Comment: Why?  What's the value of a self-link?

Comment: @JoeC because the class name might need to be changed. I know it won't be a big deal. I am just curious.

Comment: If you are changing the class name, you should be doing using IDE's (like Idea or Eclipse) refactor -> rename so that it will take care replacing it in all the places like where it is being used or imported, while doing that it will also take care javadoc as well.

Comment: good point guys, but...I am really wondering is there a way to do the self-link?

Comment: I don't think there is a way you can self-reference to the class. One work-around is to use `@see #YourClassConstructor` which will link to the constructor. Same like putting the class name - but some other ideas where you can start your research.

Comment: alright man, thanks a lot